# Populating a select box with JSON array results

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, select

So I'm trying to populate a select box within my html with array objects using JSON results, I've been looking at all this code so long I don't think I'm seeing the simple solution to my problem. This is my callback function where I'm populating the select box. The JSON request has went through fine but I am stuck with a blank select box everytime.

```
function getArtistsCallBack()
    {
        if (req.readyState == 4) {
            if (req.status == 200) {
                // TO DO: populate artistlist select box using JSON
                var response = req.responseText.parseJSON();
                var artistSelect = document.getElementById("artistlist");
                for (i=0;i<response.artistsarray.length;i++){
                    var artist_id = response.artistsarray[i].artist;
                    var artist = response.artistsarray[i].artist;               
                    artistSelect.options[artistSelect.options.length] = new Option(artist, artist_id, false, true);

                }   
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the select box within the HTML for reference just in case;

```
<div id="artistscontent">
        <select id="artistlist"></select>

         </div>
```

This is artists.php where a database is queried for an array of objects, the array that is used previously;

```
<?php
    // Include utility files
    require_once 'include/config.php';  

    // Load the database handler
    require_once BUSINESS_DIR . 'database_handler.php'; 

    // Load Business Tier
    require_once BUSINESS_DIR . 'collection.php';

    $artistsarray = Collection::GetArtists();
    print json_encode($artistsarray);

    $jsonresponse='{"artistsarray":[';  
    foreach($artistsarray as $artist => $row)               
    {
        $artist_id=$artist+1;
        $artist=$row['artist'];
        $jsonresponse .= '"artist_id":"' . $artist_id . '"},';  
        $jsonresponse .= '"artist:"' . $artist . '"},';

    }
    $jsonresponse .= ']}';
    echo $jsonresponse; 
?>
```

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Can you please provide the input JSON file?

Comment: And what framework are you using is this Node.js?

Comment: What do you get when you `console.log(response);`?

Comment: Did any of the answers help you?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the json length for the options array and do it outside of the for loop. Then use options.add

```
  var json = [{key:'1', value:'value1'},{key:'2', value:'value2'}]
  var artistSelect = document.getElementById("artistlist");
  artistSelect.options[json.length];
  $.each(json, function(key, value){
    console.debug(value);
    artistSelect.options.add(new Option(value.key, value.value));
  });
```

Check out this plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/i3A6mo672CskXvbstWsu?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

The `artistSelect.options` is not an array, you need to use the `add` method:

```
var opt = new Option(artist, artist_id);
artistSelect.options.add(opt);
```